# Is there stigma associated with self-answers on certain network sites? Or different etiquette? If so, why?

Tags: discussion, etiquette, self-answer, culture

##### Background

I was [told in chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/9385487#9385487) that some sites don't / might not see self-answers in a positive light, which I found surprising, having read the (fairly old) ["It’s OK to Ask and Answer Your Own Questions"](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) blog post, which is linked-to directly in the Ask Question UI, and the ["*Can I answer my own questions, even if I knew the answer before asking?*"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17463/997587) FAQ post here on MSE. It made me wonder- Is it truly the case that some network sites don't receive self-answers and self-answered-questions well? And if so, why?

##### "Research"

One (completely baseless!) theory I thought of to possibly explain this (if it really exists) is that experts like challenging questions, and maybe they dislike finding a question with self-answers they find satisfactory because it doesn't present a challenge to them / tickle their expertise bone. I strongly suspect that this theory is wrong, but it was the first thing that popped into my mind, so I thought it to be worth stating so that it can either be constructively disproved or confirmed.

##### Question

Is it true for any specific network sites that there is a general stigma among the site regulars (particularly answerers- i.e. the experts) against self-answers? (disapproval of / "discrimination" against. *For example*, disapproval that materializes as downvotes) Or do any specific network sites have different, specific etiquette/guidelines for self-answering? If so, for those sites, *why*?

##### Purpose

I'm asking this because I want to participate on the network with good etiquette and to be forewarned-about / mentally-prepared-for running up against any stigma against self-answers.

##### Finer Details of the Question

1. I'm not talking about self-answers where the question or the self-answer have issues that violate official Stack Exchange-wide or widely-accepted-on-site-specific-meta community guidelines. I'm talking about stigma particularly and only against the fact of the Q&A being a self-answered one: Questions that stand alone as well-formed, on-topic, not-too-localized, good-fit-for-SE questions, and self-answers that *stand alone* as well-formed, complete, useful answers. This question is not a duplicate of ["*What are limitations on self-answered questions?*"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/235177/997587) or the similar post on MSO: ["*What are the limits for self-answers? When are they (not) acceptable?*"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/278206/11107541)
2. I'm not talking about self-answers to questions where the answer to the question could be found outside the SE network in a short time (for example, 5 minutes) by googling the title. I don't think a large volume of such Q&A posts would really serve the goal to make the internet a better place.
3. [puzzling.se] and [codereview.se] are out of scope for this question, since puzzling [has a loose "protocol" / etiquette for self-answering](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2799/81581), and [so does codereview](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765/267244), and both are quite different beasts than the other more conventional knowledge-sharing network sites.
4. I have tried to pose this question following [the guidelines for asking constructive subjective questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). Prefer sharing experiences rather than opinions. Back up any opinions with facts and references. Keep in mind the purpose for which this question is asked. If you know that any network sites that have specific etiquette/protocols for self-answering like [puzzling.se], please link to them and summarize their rationale.

Comment: My theory is that self-answering is looked at as a sort of reputation harvesting scheme (by uninformed users (which can also include regulars)).

Comment: Related: *[Is there an etiquette for answering questions originally intended to be self-answered?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/349155/is-there-an-etiquette-for-answering-questions-originally-intended-to-be-self-ans)*, *[A way to reduce criticism and down-voting for answering your own question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118042/a-way-to-reduce-criticism-and-down-voting-for-answering-your-own-question)*, and *[Is there an etiquette for asking questions originally intended to be self-answered?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/349140/)*

Comment: Some examples of both good and bad self-answered answers might be in order.

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum Yes, but I'd say maybe just examples of good ones, since "bad" questions and their self-answers are out of scope here. I can go looking myself, but it'd hard for me to do widely since I only have so much SMEise (very very little in very very few topics (how do I know what's really good?)), and it's not immediately obvious to me what heuristic to use to help search/query for good-but-poorly-received content involving self-answers.

Answer (score 11):

I feel like it's very much a matter of perceived intent more than anything else. If it's a 'low hanging fruit' type question or a simple one, that's self-answered, it might not go great.

If it's an attempt at sharing documentation for a difficult problem, or sharing the solution to a difficult problem found before, it's likely to go better.

I generally feel Jeff had a good handle on how things should have worked, and while the post is old, the advice it gives is still very relevant.

No one's going to get mad at a *great*, interesting Q&A pair. Some good/difficult problems are resolved cause you kept hammering at the problem and found the answer yourself or elsewhere. And it's certainly good to avoid the [Denvercoder Problem](https://xkcd.com/979/), and close the loop.

Sometimes though the question answer pairs are not great. They might be a 'duh' moment, or ending up rubber ducking a problem. Sometimes it's an odd topic of obsession. Then we have problems.

Fundamentally it shouldn't matter, nor should there be a stigma about self-answers.

Comment: I think this does not fully answer the question, which was "**is** there a stigma on some sites", not "**should** there be a stigma". Unless you mean to imply "self-answered questions are accepted by the communities of all sites (except Puzzling) provided they are _good_ self-answered questions", which could (should!) be true, but may need some supporting evidence - for example a SEDE query for downvoted self-answered questions and a manual analysis on different sites to spot check if they are indeed bad.

Comment: I'm not sure if the numbers alone would show if there's a stigma - its entirely possible one site gets 'bad' self answers and another dosen't *and* the way sites handle things are so very different between say meta, a big site and a smaller one.

Comment: That's why I added the manual analysis remark, if you find downvoted self-answered questions, and you look at them yourself and they are actually not so bad (and/or not worse than other questions on that site that are _not_ downvoted), then that is indicative of a stigma. Another perhaps easier way is to search on each individual meta site to see if the concept of self-answering is discussed, and if negative sentiments are expressed then that is also indicative of a stigma.

Answer (score 3):

### An in-progress answer based on site-wide meta discussions

This is a work-in-progress community wiki answer with the goal of building up a list of annotated links to (mainly) discussion posts across the network's *meta* sites that contain possible indicators of approval or stigma of self-answers, or "neutral" re-inforcement of the expectations of quality for Q&A posts, or contain discussion on etiquette/practice for self-answering on that site, such that the list can eventually be used to form an answer to the question.

Entries in the current listing were found by a full pass over the following search query on stackexchange.com: [`is:question closed:no [self-answer] [discussion]`](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+closed%3Ano+%5Bself-answer%5D+%5Bdiscussion%5D). That first pass is not exempt from the effects of human-and-other-timing-related-errors (i.e. @starball might have missed some).

I (@starball) have not yet had the time (and motivation (I need a break after sifting through a 366-result search query)) to annotate this list to summarize what relevant info can be gleaned from each post, but I will do so when I have that time and motivation. Or you can do it! Unfortunately for me, it turns out that [there are many more discussion posts](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3aquestion+closed%3ano+-%5bself-answer%5d+self-answer+%5bdiscussion%5d) containing "self-answer" that don't have [self-answer](/questions/tagged/self-answer). It'll take me a while to go through those (I've now gone through the first 5 pages, and the following pages seem to be less relevant).

The list of sites is ordered [by traffic](https://stackexchange.com/sites#traffic). Entries of each site's list are (attempted to be) roughly ordered with posts that are more relevant here higher up in the list (somewhat subjective and hard to do).

##### Posts on meta.stackexchange.com

- [Etiquette for answering your own question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question)
- [Consistently Answering your Own Questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23712/consistently-answering-your-own-questions)
- [Is it a problem if a user posts "many" self answered questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/297432/is-it-a-problem-if-a-user-posts-many-self-answered-questions)
- [Posting self-answered questions for information: Should they be community wiki?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/153113/posting-self-answered-questions-for-information-should-they-be-community-wiki)
- [Was it improper for me to answer my own question in these two cases?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202758/was-it-improper-for-me-to-answer-my-own-question-in-these-two-cases)
- [What can be done to improve moderation of self-answered questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137353/what-can-be-done-to-improve-moderation-of-self-answered-questions)
- [Are there statistics as to how the instant self-answer is being used?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141114/are-there-statistics-as-to-how-the-instant-self-answer-is-being-used)
- [Is it advantageous to a beta site to postpone or abstain from answering your own question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253306/is-it-advantageous-to-a-beta-site-to-postpone-or-abstain-from-answering-your-own)
- [If I find useful information that I couldn't find on SO, should I create and then answer a question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146841/if-i-find-useful-information-that-i-couldnt-find-on-so-should-i-create-and-the)
- [First self-answered question, opinions please?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197303/first-self-answered-question-opinions-please)
- [Should my self-answered question be deleted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156271/should-my-self-answered-question-be-deleted)

##### Posts on meta.stackoverflow.com

- [How do I ask and self-answer a correct, high quality Q&A pair without attracting downvotes?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314165/how-do-i-ask-and-self-answer-a-correct-high-quality-qa-pair-without-attracting-downvotes)
- [Users who keep asking and answering their own questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316738/users-who-keep-asking-and-answering-their-own-questions)
- [Housekeeping my own self-answered questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294677/housekeeping-my-own-self-answered-questions)
- [Why are two self-answered questions about new Java 14+ features so heavily downvoted?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/404681/why-are-two-self-answered-questions-about-new-java-14-features-so-heavily-downvoted)
- [Self-answered questions about basic concepts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260781/self-answered-questions-about-basic-concepts)
- [Are self-answered questions with a very narrow scope on-topic?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289064/are-self-answered-questions-with-a-very-narrow-scope-on-topic)
- [How should one handle this simple, instantly self-answered question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/413350/how-should-one-handle-this-simple-instantly-self-answered-question)

##### Posts on meta.askubuntu.com

- https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/16747/downvotes-for-answering-own-questions

##### Posts on meta.superuser.com

- [What is the etiquette surrounding Asking and Answering Your Own Questions](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/7184/what-is-the-etiquette-surrounding-asking-and-answering-your-own-questions)
- [Can a Q&A be too minor?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/12153/can-a-qa-be-too-minor)

##### Posts on math.meta.stackexchange.com

- [Is self answering own questions a frowned upon practice in math-stack exchange?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32467/is-self-answering-own-questions-a-frowned-upon-practice-in-math-stack-exchange)
- [Recently rolled out SE Encyclopedia feature.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4286/recently-rolled-out-se-encyclopedia-feature)
- [In what situation would one answer their own question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23542/in-what-situation-would-one-answer-their-own-question)
- [Is answering own question okay?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4680/is-answering-own-question-okay)
- [Posting a question for the purpose of posting an answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30807/posting-a-question-for-the-purpose-of-posting-an-answer)
- [Can I post a question and an answer just because I think it helps others?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15017/can-i-post-a-question-and-an-answer-just-because-i-think-it-helps-others)
- [Unsure about answering-self question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19842/unsure-about-answering-self-question)
- [can one ask a question one came up with oneself and one knows the answer to](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34206/can-one-ask-a-question-one-came-up-with-oneself-and-one-knows-the-answer-to) (about "puzzle" questions. question was asked on puzzling.se)
- [Deciding Whether to Self-Answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22948/deciding-whether-to-self-answer)

##### Posts on salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com

- https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3018/why-dont-we-see-more-self-answered-questions

##### Posts on stats.meta.stackexchange.com

- https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1844/encouraging-questioners-to-answer-their-own-self-study-questions etiquette proposal for questions tagged ["self-study"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info)

##### Posts on gis.meta.stackexchange.com

- https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5255/is-it-necessary-to-add-a-minimal-code-to-question-when-self-answering

##### Posts on physics.meta.stackexchange.com

- [Best of PSE 2016 - Best self-answered post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9485/best-of-pse-2016-best-self-answered-post) A POLL question for best of 2016!
- [Posting and self answering basic derivations](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13521/posting-and-self-answering-basic-derivations)

##### Posts on english.meta.stackexchange.com

- https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3453/answering-at-the-same-time-as-asking-ok

##### Posts on gaming.meta.stackexchange.com

- https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10835/is-a-self-answered-question-appropriate-in-this-case

##### Posts on datascience.meta.stackexchange.com

- https://datascience.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2547/can-we-ask-questions-and-answer-them-by-our-self

##### Posts rpg.meta.stackexchange.com

- [Are self-answer questions still allowed?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9372/are-self-answer-questions-still-allowed)
- [Is there a way to let someone else decide which answer to accept? How should accepting self-answers be handled?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9393/is-there-a-way-to-let-someone-else-decide-which-answer-to-accept-how-should-acc)
- [What is the problem with my question about erotic roleplay in online RP?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6749/what-is-the-problem-with-my-question-about-erotic-roleplay-in-online-rp) very small section in top answer about higher standard
- [Should I post self-answered questions, for rules I clarify for my players?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4769/should-i-post-self-answered-questions-for-rules-i-clarify-for-my-players) no stigma
- [Would it be considered bad etiquette to self-answer a question summarizing points from other answers and comments?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4778/would-it-be-considered-bad-etiquette-to-self-answer-a-question-summarizing-points-from-other-answers-and-comments)

##### Posts on ell.meta.stackexchange.com

- https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2585/am-i-right-no-youre-wrong policy/etiquette suggestion for "am I right" questions

##### Posts academia.meta.stackexchange.com

- https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1168/downvotes-on-answers-becuase-they-come-from-the-tools-author Not stigma against self-answers- against low-quality, self-promoting posts.

#### meta.mathoverflow.net

- https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4766/please-help-me-improve-my-qa-and-possibly-reopen-certain-questions#comment24207_4766 comment: community wiki better for optics. this site "unique" in network?

##### Posts on webapps.meta.stackexchange.com

- https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/318/is-it-ok-to-submit-an-answer-to-a-question-that-you-yourself-have-asked/
- https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2461/is-it-ok-to-seed-questions-and-answers

##### Posts on gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com

- https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2704/whats-our-stance-on-self-answered-questions-that-dont-show-any-research-effort

##### Posts on scifi.meta.stackexchange.com

- https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9819/should-we-revisit-the-self-answer-policy
- https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9755/under-what-conditions-is-self-answering-story-identification-questions-conside

  > Firstly you need to be aware there are some users who will insta-downvote **practically anything** that's self-answered, regardless of the [quality](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/129319/why-is-the-matrix-tinted-green) of the question and the answer simply because they disagree with the site policy and this is their way of showing it.

##### Posts on dsp.meta.stackexchange.com

- https://dsp.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1538/self-answering-without-peer-review-benefit-or-harmful

##### Posts on worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com

- https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6448/structure-of-a-question-giving-your-own-calculations-as-an-answer-or-including some people have higher standard
- https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1971/ethics-of-answering-ones-own-question-when-it-has-very-low-votes asker thinks there is higher standard

##### Posts on quant.meta.stackexchange.com

- https://quant.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1449/self-answering-questions-acceptable-on-quant-or-not no stigma, but maybe higher standard

##### Posts on politics.meta.stackexchange.com

- https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2678/how-self-answered-questions-are-accepted

##### Posts on movies.meta.stackexchange.com

- https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4693/etiquette-when-answering-own-question
- https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/427/is-it-okay-to-answer-your-own-question-within-few-minutes

##### Posts on hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com

- https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/303/self-answering-posts

##### Posts on bitcoin.meta.stackexchange.com

- https://bitcoin.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253/what-is-the-limit-of-self-answering

##### Posts on anime.meta.stackexchange.com

- https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1038/should-we-allow-identification-request-questions-where-the-questioner-already-knows-the-answer Note: indentification questions are now off-topic there.

##### Posts on biology.meta.stackexchange.com

- https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1870/question-and-self-answering-continued

##### Posts on islam.meta.stackexchange.com

- https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2962/are-there-any-examples-of-self-answered-qas-on-this-site General disdain due to past instances of bad Q&A

##### Posts on codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com

- https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12103/self-answering-kick-starts-answers-or-discourages-them Etiquette: wait a bit.

##### Posts on photo.meta.stackexchange.com

- https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5704/self-answered-questions

##### Posts on judaism.meta.stackexchange.com

- https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/306/if-i-know-the-answer-to-a-question

##### Posts on ham.meta.stackexchange.com

- https://ham.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/343/helping-new-user-with-posting-an-excellent-self-answered-question

##### Posts on literature.meta.stackexchange.com

- https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/826/is-it-worth-posting-self-answers-for-relatively-easy-or-obscure-questions

##### Posts on iot.meta.stackexchange.com

- https://iot.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109/theres-no-shame-in-self-answering

##### Posts on buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com

- https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2481/what-about-self-answering-questions seems to be talking about bad Qs and bad As. if anything, stigma here is probably against bad Q&A(?)
- https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2500/proposal-self-answering-questions-is-welcome "turnaround" and new policy more in line with rest of SE network

##### Posts on genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com

- https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1721/are-we-happy-to-see-more-self-answered-questions

##### Posts on proofassistants.meta.stackexchange.com

- https://proofassistants.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33/policy-on-self-answers A poll!

##### Posts on hardwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com

- https://hardwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/246/how-do-we-feel-about-self-answering Observed higher standard

##### Posts on windowsphone.meta.stackexchange.com (archived)

- https://windowsphone.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256/etiquette-for-self-answering-questions